# Cypress: Is it possible to fetch the entire json data from the json file, placed in the fixtures folder and paste it's content in the textarea?

Tags: json, cypress

As per the cypress doc we can use the below command for fetching the respective item from the json and comparing it's value.
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/swagger-sample.json').its('openapi').should('eq', '3.0.0') 
This reads the respective variables value for comparing

What if we want to get the entire json data and populate it somewhere?
If either cy.readFile / cy.fixtures should fetch the entire data of the json file as such which can be made as content to a textarea, similar to copy the json data paste it in the textarea.

Answer (score 3):

See Cypress doc on [cy.fixture()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Arguments).

To get file content from **cypress/fixtures/**, use:

```
cy.fixture('swagger-sample.json').then(fixtureContent => {
  expect(fixtureContent).to.have.property('openapi', '3.0.0');

  // to put content in textarea
  cy.get('textarea_selector').clear().type(JSON.stringify(fixtureContent));
});
```